# Mac won't autocorrect 'hte'

Tags: dictionary, spellcheck

This has been going on for way too long and I'm hoping someone can help me.

For whatever reason, the last two Macs I've had have stopped autocorrecting the word 'hte'. I could of course just learn how to type 'the' but I feel like since the computer is autocorrecting everything else I type, I'm not sure why it is so difficult to correct this obvious typo. This is seemingly the only word my Mac struggles with.

Has anyone else experienced this and has a solution?

Thoughts anyone? Thanks!

I could make a text substitution via keyboard in System Preferences but this would only work for certain apps (and it wouldn't cover all the different permutations that I would need like Hte etc.) I've tried looking and I think the word isn't in my dictionary and I can't 'unlearn' hte so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it hasn't accidentally been added to a user dictionary.
Look in `~/Library/Spelling/`. Mine contains three text-editable user dictionaries - I have no idea why three or quite what they do, but they contain 'my words' in various forms.

[image]

The files will open in TextEdit or your chosen text editor on double-click. You can add or delete from them with no restrictions [I don't know when they are read, so if you discover after removing a word it is still recognised, reboot & test again.]

Comment: So whatever reason I have a LocalDictionary like yourself and three dat files - tried grepping "^hte$" in each file and nothing came up. Opening the dat files reveals some content I do'nt understand and double checking manually in the LocalDictionary also reveals 'hte' isn't there...

Comment: Hmmm…OK I'm not sure where else it could be. Let's hope someone else has a better idea. Wish you luck.